# ERB iteration not displaying div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I've created an erb iteration that iterates over a number of products which generates a corresponding product image and a div (.tagged) that lays on top of the image. The problem is when theres only one out connection (i_connection) no div is shown, but when there are more than one, the correct number of divs displays. Any idea what's going on here?

```
<% if @new_manual.present? %>
  <% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>

    <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
    <span class="connection" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>"></span>

    <% o_connection = Contact.find(step.output_contact) %>
    <% cord = CordType.find(step.contact_item) %>

    <%= o_connection.product.full_name %>
    uses a <%= cord.name %>
    to plug into <%= i_connection.product.full_name %><br>
    <%= image_tag(o_connection.image.image.url(:medium)) %>

    <br>
    <%= image_tag(cord.image.url(:thumb)) %><br>
    <br>
    <div id='image_panel'>
      <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:medium)) %>
      <div id='planetmap'></div>
    </div>

    <%= image_tag(cord.image.url(:thumb)) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where is this div? Please add important excerpt.

Comment: The div (.target) is appended to the planet map div with this line of jQuery
        $('#planetmap').append('<div class="tagged"  style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
        pos_height+'px;left:'+xpos+'px;top:'+ypos+'px;" ><div class="tagged_box" style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
        pos_height+'px;display:none;" ></div>')
         }

Comment: You have two `<% end %>`s where do those blocks start?

Comment: My apologies, all fixed.

Comment: WTF you add the same js for each step?

Comment: If you couldn't tell, I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing. Haha I guess I should take that out of the block then?

Comment: Yes you should, be DRY!

Comment: Pro tip - use two space "soft indent" in your code, not 8 space tabs.

Comment: Also - is `span.connection` generated properly for a single step? If so this is a problem with your javascript and not with Rails.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be generating properly. But you're right it is probably more of a jQuery problem. Thanks for the help